# Python supervised ML text classification into different categories with probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, twitter, supervised-learning

I am working with a large dataset of tweets from which I have trained a small subset into four manually classified categories. The manual classifications have about twenty tweets each, while the dataset has tens of thousands of tweets. Here is the code I used to train the model.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

tweets = []
labels_list = []
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=5, norm='l2', 
encoding='latin-1', ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
features = tfidf.fit_transform(tweets).toarray()
labels = labels_list

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(tweets, labels, 
random_state = 0)
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
```

Whenever I type

```
print(clf.predict(count_vect.transform(["Some random content"])))
```

the machine accurately outputs the label that the tweet belongs to if I fill in the content with something that matches the training data. However, if I type in total nonsense, it will also output some random category that I know it doesn't belong to.

My goal is to find 100 tweets that are most likely to belong to that category, however, the four categories mentioned above are not representative of the entire dataset, therefore, I need to know if there some sort of probability threshold I could use to eliminate that tweet and not add it to the 100 if it is too low on the threshold?

I tried looking into multinomial logistic regression but I could not find any sort of probability output, so maybe if I am just doing something wrong or if there is another way I would like to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.predict_proba()` method on your `clf` to get probabilities of every class for every tweet. Then to get top-100 tweets for, say, class 0, you sort all your tweets by the probability of class 0 and take top 100.

You can do it easily with `pandas` for instance:

```
import pandas as pd
probsd = pd.DataFrame(clf.predict_proba(Xtest_tfidf))
top_100_class_0_tweets = probsd.sort_values(0, ascending=False).head(100).index
```

Comment: I'm using text classification for news types like sports,politics,business,entertainment using logistic regression and the text which doesn't belongs to the above categories are also predicted as one of the category. How to prevent this in machine learning? also how to add out of category text to other_category label?